# "does not contain a default export" even though one is declared

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, node-modules, commonjs

Software rots. I made a minor change to a three year-old GitHub project and the rebuild failed due to automatic security patches. Got everything fixed except for a default import failure.

The error is:

```
ERROR in ./src/HeatMapTable.js 340:20-27
export 'default' (imported as 'HeatMap') was not found in 'jsheatmap' (module has no exports)
```

Here's the relevant code:

main.js

```
import HeatMap, { Style } from "jsheatmap";  //eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

jhheatmap, index.ts

```
class Sterno {...}
...
export { Style, Sterno as default }
```

if I look at what is in node-modules, the **jsheatmap/lib/index.js** file shows:

```
var Sterno = /** @class */ (function () {...}
...
exports.default = Sterno;
```

If I remember my CommonJS correctly, the above export should be compatible with the ECMAScript import used in **main.js**.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "jsheatmap",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "description": "Generates heat map data",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:live",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "build:live": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.ts"
  },...
```

Comment: What's your tsconfig look like? Also, the error says "module has no exports"...

Comment: It is an npm module. Index.js is the entry point. I'll add the tsconfig to the OP

Comment: I know, but it seems that TypeScript or whatever you're using doesn't believe that it has any exports.

Comment: This was working, and the link to the app is below. I only made a small change to a stylesheet, and it's been nothing but trouble.  https://pokermap.netlify.app/

Comment: What's the content of *node-modules/jsheatmap/package.json*? The *index.ts* source file seems irrelevant.

Comment: [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), did you see the index.js in the OP?

Comment: What is outputting this error? What is the build tooling? Webpack/rollup/tsc? I tried a minimal example with just tsc and all is fine. (Other than having to add allowJs to the tsconfig.)

Comment: Went to the app and clicked around, is this [repo](https://github.com/JeffML/pokermap) for it? If so, do you have a branch in the current state in question?

Comment: Hi, AllenWithPizza.  I made one change to a stylesheet in the master branch, but encountered a slew of errors when building. I assume this is because of dependabot updates and non-working versions of modules.  Anyhow, I just checked in a "draft" branch which contains the source of what I changed to "fix" the master branch. I also switched from npm to yarn, which I don't think is the problem, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I successfully deployed your latest commit: https://pokermap.vercel.app/**

- The package-lock.json file makes it possible to use the exact versions of the NPM modules at the time of the commit.
- Your project seems to be compatible with node 16, but not node 18.

**How to successfully start your project locally:**

```
git clone https://github.com/JeffML/pokermap.git
cd pokermap
npm ci      # Install module versions form package-lock.json
npm start   # Must be node version 16
```

**How to successfully deploy your project:**

Ensure node version 16 is used:

- You can modify the package.json `engines` config.
- Vercel also allows you to configure the node version via the web settings interface.
- I believe Netlify deprecated and no longer supports node version 16.

Comment: Thank you Leftnum.  I saw your commit and ran the app and it looks just as I expected. I will merge your changes.

Comment: @JeffLowery: I didn't commit any changes; I just used a different process for starting/deploying the code you already commited. (https://github.com/Leftium/pokermap/commits/main)

Comment: Okay, my misunderstanding. What I wound up doing was fiddling with a couple of settings in tsconfig (target and module to "es2019" and "es2015", respectively; and moduleResolution set to "node"). I had to use .js extensions for the imports, but that was about it. Rebuild and redeployed to npm and everythings okay now.

Answer (score -3):

You can try out `export default class Sterno {...}`

I would recommend to you [this article for different ways to import and export](https://javascript.info/import-export)